# How to conditionally pass optional props to component when we use React with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

When we use React with Typescript we can define optional props:

```
interface SomeProps {
  required: string
  optional?: number
}

const SomeComponent = ({ required, optional }: SomeProps): JSX.Element => { ...
```

When we use it later we can pass, or omit the optional property:

```
<SomeComponent required="abc" />
<SomeComponent required="def" optional={1} />
```

When we want to do it dynamically with React without Typescript we can pass undefined to optional property:

```
<SomeComponent required="ghi" optional={optionalValue ? optionalValue : undefined } />
```

But with Typescript that way doesn't work. Typescript transpiler will warn us that type `number | undefined` is not assignable to `number`. Of course we can wrap it in `if` statement and repeat `SomeComponent` usage but it's not the most elegant solution...

How can we conditionally pass optional props to component when we use React with Typescript?

**UPDATE**

I beg your pardon. I was wrong. This way of course works with Typescript as well. I didn't notice some internals in my code (which wasn't part of the question).

Answer (score 1):

```js
import React from 'react'

interface SomeProps {
  required: string
  optional?: number
}

const SomeComponent = ({ required, optional }: SomeProps) => null

const x = <SomeComponent required="abc" />
const y = <SomeComponent required="def" optional={1} />

const Foo = (optional?: number) =>
  <SomeComponent required="ghi" optional={optional ? optional : undefined} />
```

It works in [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChTgA7GJKTdJOAZVyQAUcwBnOAb1LhwiARwCuwIgBMAXHC4woVAOYC4EMDGARKKADYB%20WZVEgARrVIBfcmm3zmrAMK5IlJNTgBeOAApeQpDEJJEkAGjUNLR1dOEtZFhB2Ti4ASi8APjhjXV0bO3gADy84AB4EpGdwbXd4EXEpTwAiFFM0RrgAenTSW0p7AE9isqcXao864MkmySRMdvVNbT1PXgBGS07unvy4ADEICGKfBai9QyyTcyg0z27BYcTK1xqAoIbGpQALYHnIpd0Vid-nB9BFFtE4LJRJQZpgqCENl1yKQgA)

Comment: Yes, not adding optional prop works, but `optional={optionalValue ? optionalValue : undefined }` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple types for the *optional* prop.
In your case, the possible types are number & undefined. So you can define the optional prop as:

```
interface SomeProps {
      required: string
      optional?: number | undefined
    }
```